# Can I simplify this code for return views? It seems very redundant

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Is there a way to shrink these into just one group result? I have a set of pages like these which simply return static content and thought there must be a more efficient way to do it.

```
    public ActionResult Research()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Facility()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

EDIT:  Thanks for all the replies :)

Comment: This is code in a controller from microsoft's ASP.NET MVC3 framework.

Comment: You can remove newlines.

Comment: Yes, spacially it is possible to remove the space they take up, such as grouping them in a region and just minimizing it away.  But I was hoping there was a way to use an array or a struct or something to apply the generic "return view()" to.

Comment: How many different views do you want to pack in the array? For less than 10 I would say that this (above) is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make a shared action method that takes a `viewName` parameter:

```
public ActionResult Show(string viewName)
{
    return View(viewName);
}
```

You can then route those names to this action:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Simple Content",
    "/{viewName}",
    new { controller = "Something", action = "Show" },
    new { viewName = "Research|Facility|Contact" }
);
```

The `viewName` constraint is required to prevent this route from matching arbitrary URLs.

Beware that this is an information disclosure vulnerability; an attacker can request `/ControllerName/Show?viewName=~/Views/Secret/View`.
If you have any confidential views that don't use models, you should validate the `viewName` in the action.
To do that, you can use an enum, as in [dknaack's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8719213/34397).

Comment: You beat me to it. I think this is actually less intuitive and less scalable way of doing it and I personally would leave it as it is (OP).

Answer (score 2):

You could create a new route that would take only `controllername/{path}`, and the path will be your name of the view then in controller action something like this

```
public ActionResult Page(string path)
{
    return View(path);
}
```

So going to this path

`yourdomain.com/controllername/Ijusttest` will load a view from `~/Views/controllername/Ijusttest.cshtml`. You just have to be sure to call you action from route.

I hope that makes sense. You can set it up differently, it is all up to the routing that you create. Let me know if you need help wit route code.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create one action and pass an argument as the page name, for example

```
public StaticContent : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Pages(string id)
  {
    return View(id);
  }
}
```

Where id can have the values "Research", "Facility", etc.

You would get url like these /staticcontent/pages/research

Just name the Views on the StaticContent folder Research.cshtml for example.